# Powershell script for replacing multiple PDF files in Document library with new names

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have multiple files under the document library folder "Documents" which needs to be replaced with new names.
Example: hello123.pdf needs to be replaced with hello789.pdf
below is a sample I have tried with filename_old having the existing filenames and filenames_new aving the new set of names.How do I loop both in the below

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "https://test.com"
$DocLib = $Web.Lists["Documents"]           
$filename_old  = Get-Content 'F:\user\test1.txt' | old file names
$filename_new  = Get-Content 'F:\user\test2.txt' | new file names
$outputFile = 'F:\users\RenameResults.csv'

# loop through each item of the text file
$result = foreach($name in $filenames) {
    # try and find a listitem name that has the $name in it
    $renamed = foreach ($ListItem in ($DocLib.Items | Where-Object { $_["Name"] -like "*$name*" })) {
        $oldName = $ListItem["Name"]
        $newName = $name 
        $ListItem.File.CheckOut()
        $ListItem["Name"] = $newName
        $ListItem.Update()
        $ListItem.File.CheckIn($ListItem["Name"] + ".pdf")
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            SearchName      = $name
            OldListItemName = $oldName
            NewListItemName = $newName
        }
    }
    
    if (!$renamed) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            SearchName      = $name
            OldListItemName = 'Not found'
            NewListItemName = ''
        }        
    }
    else { $renamed }
}

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: _`foreach($name in $filenames)`_.. you have not defined `$filenames`

Comment: I think it would be easier to create an input CSV file containinge the old and new names if they can't be calculated, instead of two separat lists. Are that comments behind the `|` in row 2 and 3? In Powershell you do that with `#`... + What @Theo said.

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest you to use foreach, because then you can only use `Where-Object {$_["Name"] -like "*$name*"}` to get listitem, which will appear when there are multiple files with similar names in the library problem.

My test code for your reference(But this method needs to keep the order in the two texts consistent):

```
 $filename_old  = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\test1.txt' 
    $filename_new  = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\test2.txt'
    $outputFile = 'C:\Temp\RenameResults.csv'
    $Web = Get-SPWeb "http://sp"
    $DocLib = $Web.Lists["Documents"] 
    $listItemData=@()
    for($i=0;$i -lt $filename_old.Count;$i++){
    
        # try and find a listitem name that has the $name in it
        $renamed = foreach ($ListItem in ($DocLib.Items | Where-Object { $_["Name"] -eq $filename_old[$i] })) {
            $oldName = $ListItem["Name"]
            $newName = $filename_new[$i] 
            $ListItem.File.CheckOut()
            $ListItem["Name"] = $newName
            $ListItem.Update()
            $ListItem.File.CheckIn($ListItem["Name"] + ".pdf")
            $listItemData += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                SearchName      = $name
                OldListItemName = $oldName
                NewListItemName = $newName
            }
            
        }
        
        if (!$renamed) {
            $listItemData += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                SearchName      = $name
                OldListItemName = 'Not found'
                NewListItemName = ''
            }        
        }
        else { $renamed }
    }
    $listItemData | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```